# The index operator

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can someone explain to me why:

```
print(my_list[-1])
```

Is the same as:

```
print (my_list[len(my_list) - 1])
```

And how is this a shortcut to avoid writing

```
len(my_list)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When doing `print(my_list[-1])` you are printing the last value of `my_list`. See slicing of python.

When doing `print (my_list[len(my_list) - 1])` you are printing the last value of `my_list`.
In this way you are getting a positive integer from `len(my_list) - 1`.

While `len(my_list)` returns the number of elements in `my_list`. Note that the slicing notation in python starts with 0 and `len` counts elements starting with 1.

Answer (score 4):

This is the case purely because Python defines it to be the case. A negative index is treated as counting from the end of the list (or string, or tuple) instead of the start. To quote [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations), referring to `my_list[i]`, and extended forms `my_list[i:j]` and `my_list[i:j:k]`:

> If `i` or `j` is negative, the index is relative to the end of the string:
>   `len(s) + i` or `len(s) + j` is substituted. But note that -0 is still 0.

Most third-party types implementing the sequence protocol behave the same way, but note that they are not *obliged* to - it is only guaranteed behavior for the built-in sequences.

Comment: `slice.indices` is handy. Say the sequence has length 5 and the slice `[-1::-1]` is requested, i.e. `__getitem__` is passed `slice(-1,None,-1)`. Then `start, stop, step = slice(-1,None,-1).indices(5); (start, stop, step) == (4, -1, -1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Supporting negative indexes is an object specific implementation, who design the list object support it. Not all objects have to support it.

You can find where this is implemented in the [`listobject.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c#L2408):

```
static PyObject *
list_subscript(PyListObject* self, PyObject* item)
{
    if (PyIndex_Check(item)) {
        Py_ssize_t i;
        i = PyNumber_AsSsize_t(item, PyExc_IndexError);
        ...
        if (i < 0)                          // 1
            i += PyList_GET_SIZE(self);     // 2
        return list_item(self, i);          // 3
        ...
```

if the index is negative, it will add the list size to it:

```
if i < 0:
  i += len(lst)
```

Comment: Well, [`PySequence_Getitem`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/04f714765c13/Objects/abstract.c#l1498) does the translation for negative indexes if a type only supports sequence methods. Most do support `tp_as_mapping->mp_subscript`, since it's preferred by `PyObject_Getitem` and enables extended slicing. But not, e.g.,  [`_collections.deque`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/04f714765c13/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c#l1150). Negative indexes are supported via `PySequence_Getitem`, but not slicing since `tp_as_sequence->sq_item` takes an `ssize_t` index.

Answer (score 0):

lvc's answer is great, but I would like to add that this is a shortcut because
`print (my_list[-1])` is indded shorter than `print (my_list[len(my_list) - 1])`, the correct way of doing that.